# Unable to convert comma separated string to an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I am using the following code to convert a comma separated string to an array.

```
NSString *domanIdStr = [Settings getSetting:@"selectedDomainId"];
NSLog(@"%@",domanIdStr);
NSArray *domainIds = [domanIdStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

`NSLog(@"%@",domanIdStr);` prints

```
(
    "1,2"
)
```

But then the third line `componentsSeparatedByString` throws the following error,

```
[__NSCFArray componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1702650c0
```

How can I be able to sort this out ?

Comment: i think the problem is with that string domanIDStr, it prints with brackets "()", check that.

Comment: Check your [Settings getSetting:@"selectedDomainId"]; func. I think it return a array instead of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSLog(@"%@",domanIdStr);` prints

```
(
    "1,2"
)
```

`domanIdStr` is not a **string**, it is an **array**. So, to properly get the domanIdStr, use this

```
NSArray * domanIdStr = [Settings getSetting:@"selectedDomainId"];
NSString *firstTag = domanIdStr[0]; //this would be "1"
```

or else if you want to extract then do like

```
 NSArray *domanIdStr = [Settings getSetting:@"selectedDomainId"];
 NSString *getString = domanIdStr[0];
NSArray *domainIds = [getString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"%@",domanIdStr[0]);
```

Comment: actually the first element is `"1,2"`

Comment: how a array is getting in a nsstring @Anbu.Karthik bro

Comment: @R.Mohan - pardon bro

Comment: NSString *domanIdStr = [Settings getSetting:@"selectedDomainId"];  in this line selectedDomainId key is having a array with string values, how a nsarray is getting saved in a nsstring, because he is printing a nsstring, in that it prints a array right. i am thinking like if we try to save array in nsstring it should crash at that place itself right.

Comment: @R.Mohan - are you seen this `(`, its array, not a string , it is the string `"1,2"`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik ok bro, so if a array having string values, then we can get(save) that array in nsstring also..is this right..

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with following

```
NSArray *domanIdStr = [Settings getSetting:@"selectedDomainId"];
NSString *str = domanIdStr[0];
NSArray *domainIds = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting array for the key selectedDomainId that is the problem, if you get a string in that, then the problem will be fixed simply.